# request a link python

Tags: python, request

How to click in this link with python request?

```
<a onclick="return submitCheckout( 'requestRenewAll', 'requestRenewAll' )" href="#">
    <img border="0" alt="RENOVAR-LOS TOTS" src="/screens/pat_renewall_cat.gif">
</a>
```

I have created a session, I have authenticated but I can't follow this link.

```
function submitCheckout(buttonname, buttonvalue)
{
     var oHiddenID;
     oHiddenID = document.getElementById("checkoutpagecmd");

     oHiddenID.name = buttonname;
     oHiddenID.value = buttonvalue;

     document.getElementById("checkout_form").submit();
     return true;
}
```

This is javascript function. But requestRenewAll elements only find in items#. Now prove submit in this form.

Thanks. Regards.

Comment: Are you trying to access a python service through a URL?

Comment: Click on the link in the browser, see what underlying request is going and simulate it with `requests`.

Comment: That's try but the url doesn't change and with firebug I find nothing,  any idea where to start looking? Thanks for your time.

Comment: parm = { 
        "checkoutpagecmd" : "requestRenewAll",
        "checkout_form" : "submit"
        }
yes, with this run. Thankss all, alecxe love you :DD

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score -1):

```
from requests import Session, Request

url = "https://www.example.com"

parm = { 
         "checkoutpagecmd" : "requestRenewAll", 
         "checkout_form" : "submit" 
        } 

s = Session()
r = s.post(url, parm, verify=False)
```

I just followed the advice of alecxe to simulate the behavior of the function in javascript with requests for python3.